# wait for array to be filled using .push in react?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am fetching an api and pushing results to an empty array, but I need the array to be filled to display the information within the array. I am getting "cannot read property high of undefined" i'm assuming because the array is not filled before rendering, how can I wait for the for loop to be complete before rendering the page?

```
function TopStocks(props) {
 const symbols = ["AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOGL", "TSLA"];
  const stockInfo = [];


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSymbols();
  }, []);



async function fetchSymbols() {
    for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
      await fetch(
        `api&symbol=${symbols[i]}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((allStocks) => {
          try {
            let metaDataEntries = allStocks["Meta Data"];
            let symbol = metaDataEntries["2. Symbol"].toUpperCase();
            let pastDataEntries = allStocks["Time Series (Daily)"];
            let pastDataValues = Object.values(pastDataEntries);
            let mostRecentValue = pastDataValues[0];
            let x = Object.values(mostRecentValue);
            let open = parseFloat(x[0]).toFixed(2);
            let high = parseFloat(x[1]).toFixed(2);
            let low = parseFloat(x[2]).toFixed(2);
            let close = parseFloat(x[3]).toFixed(2);
            let percentage = close - open;
            let result = parseFloat(percentage).toFixed(2);

            stockInfo.push({
              symbol: symbol,
              high: high,
              low: low,
              close: close,
              open: open,
              percentage: result,
            });
          } catch {
            console.log("surpassed the limit of 4 requests in under a minute");
          }
        });
    }
  }


return (<span className="header__grid-price">{stockInfo[0].high}</span>)
}
```

Comment: Quickest solution if your environment is setup for it is to use optional chaining: `stockInfo[0]?.high`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a simple push operation on `stockInfo`, which will not trigger the rerender, for that, you have to change the state of it, use `useState` hooks instead,

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function TopStocks(props) {
  const symbols = ["AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOGL", "TSLA"];
  const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSymbols();
  }, []);

  async function fetchSymbols() {
    for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
      await fetch(`api&symbol=${symbols[i]}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((allStocks) => {
          try {
            let metaDataEntries = allStocks["Meta Data"];
            let symbol = metaDataEntries["2. Symbol"].toUpperCase();
            let pastDataEntries = allStocks["Time Series (Daily)"];
            let pastDataValues = Object.values(pastDataEntries);
            let mostRecentValue = pastDataValues[0];
            let x = Object.values(mostRecentValue);
            let open = parseFloat(x[0]).toFixed(2);
            let high = parseFloat(x[1]).toFixed(2);
            let low = parseFloat(x[2]).toFixed(2);
            let close = parseFloat(x[3]).toFixed(2);
            let percentage = close - open;
            let result = parseFloat(percentage).toFixed(2);

            let temp = [...stockInfo];
            temp.push({
              symbol: symbol,
              high: high,
              low: low,
              close: close,
              open: open,
              percentage: result
            });
            setStockInfo(temp);
          } catch {
            console.log("surpassed the limit of 4 requests in under a minute");
          }
        });
    }
  }

  return (
    <span className="header__grid-price">
      {stockInfo[0].high ? stockInfo[0].high : "loading"}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is true, and making the variable stateful is good advice, but they will still have the same error since on the first render `stockInfo` will be an empty array (having an undefined 0 index)

Comment: Yes, I believe this should fully solve their problem now. The only other advice I'd give is to maybe put a sentence or two explaining your "loading" logic since that is what addresses the error in question.

Comment: Your comments have already explained the underlying logic , thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption. Try using the `map` function as it is async along with `Promise.all` so that you block the return of that function until all of your calls have finished.

```
...
Promise.all(
  symbols.map(symbol => {
    fetch(`api&symbol=${symbol}`)
    .then(
      // whatever you want to do with it
    )
  })
);
```

Comment: That won't prevent the first render of the component, which is what it is breaking on.

Answer (score 0):

React hates it when you mutate constants. It's better to use the useState method to create the constant and the setter method.

```
const [stockInfo, setStockInfo] = useState([]); //This will default stockInfo to an empty array.
```

Then make your response dump into an array and setStockInfo() that array.

ex:

```
let newStockInfo = [];

/* Your stock gathering function here, but dumps into newStockInfo */

setStockInfo(newStockInfo);
```

That will update your stocks and prevent undefined properties.

I'm sure there is another way to do this, but this is a pretty quick way to get it done.